# Python. Как сделать, что бы вводимое ранее значение в telegram выводилось в строку ""Написать сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, бот

Ребят. Всем привет. Нужна помощь)
Есть код:

```
def edit(message):
    num = int(message.text)
    num = num - 1
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, list[num])
```

Логика проста. Человек вводит данные. Они сохраняются в список под своим номером. Потом человек вводит число, чтобы отредактировать свою запись. И вот можно ли сделать, чтобы его запись
вывелась в строку "введите сообщение", а не отдельным смс приходило.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее всем спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя, поскольку поле отправки сообщения для пользователя. Боты не могут с ним взаимодействовать

Answer (score 0):

Сохрани их в переменную, а потом вытащи

```
@tokenbot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def user_mess(ms):
    a = ms.text
    tokenbot.send_message(ms.chat.id, a)
```